# css property not found in browser when i inspect my html page?

Tags: css, html

Below i mentioned the html and css. but when i open it in browser,css property of background color and other properties not showing anything expect image.

HTML code

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Home Page One </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="type/html" charset="utf-8" />
<link href="home1.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
        <header class="headerpart">
                <img  src="images.jpg"/>

        </header>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Property

```
body
{
background:#CCCCCC;
color:#000000;
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-style:normal;
margin:0px auto;
}

.headerPart
{
 background:#00CCFF;
 margin:0px auto;
 width:1120px;
 height:30px;

}
```

when i run this html in browser, it shows only the image expect the css propety of background and everthing. when i inspect the html, browser showing the css property not found..

am looking solution for this problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS Classes are case sensitive.  You have `class="headerpart"` in your html but your CSS says `.headerPart` with a capitol `P`.  Change one or the other, and you should see the behaviour you want.

Comment: Also, `rel="stylesheet"` is missing from the `link` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add rel="stylesheet" to your link tag, like following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home1.css" type="text/css" />
```